# Android Touch Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-2dtools

I want to know how to move an object Left or Right by touching. Something like:

```
public float speed;

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float LeftRight = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    Vector3 Movement = new Vector3 ( LeftRight, 0, 0);

    rigidbody.AddForce(Movement * speed);
}
```

But just for touching the screen. The first half of screen for left and the other for right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input type of touch in android or ios, use `Input.GetTouch`.
The idea is to get the position of the touch then decide if it's touching the left or the right side of the screen by getting the screen width using `Screen.width`.

```
public float speed;

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float LeftRight = 0;

    if(Input.touchCount > 0){
        // touch x position is bigger than half of the screen, moving right
        if(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x > Screen.width / 2)
            LeftRight = 1;
        // touch x position is smaller than half of the screen, moving left
        else if(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x < Screen.width / 2)
            LeftRight = -1;
    }

    Vector3 Movement = new Vector3 ( LeftRight, 0, 0);

    rigidbody.AddForce(Movement * speed);
}
```